# Misspelled recipent, same or unique?

Tags: email, gmail

I have x.x@gmail.com as primary email-address, but per accident i sent confidential information to xx@gmail.com (note the *dot*). How will this be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en), the dot doesn't matter and it went to your primary address anyways.

Comment: Ok! This clear things up. thanks.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this is non-standard behavior, and email providers which are more standard-compliant will consider `xx` and `x.x` as different recipients.

Comment: @Philipp Indeed, even Google's business email systems (organizations which use gmail but have their own domain) do not disregard dots. The OP specifically stated a gmail account, so I gave the behavior for a gmail account.